# Questions arisen from integral of $\int \frac{1}{e^x-e^{x-1}} dx$

Tags: integration

### Main Question

I have some beef I'd like to let loose for the following integral:

### $$\int \frac{1}{e^x-e^{-x}} dx$$

This is equivalent to the following, with the appropriate substitution of $t = e^x$:

$$\int \frac{1}{t^2-1} dt$$

I'm going to omit the proof for this but it's quite trivial and not part of my question. Now, the route my lecturer used was integration by partial fractions, and that's well and good, but my beef with the question has to do my following flawed processes, and why they aren't valid:

- Recall $cosh^2\ x - sinh^2\ x = 1$
- Hence $-sinh^2\ x - 1 = -cosh^2\ x$
- Let $-sinh\ x = t$ so $sinh^2\ x = t^2$
- $\frac{dt}{dx} = -cosh\ x$
- $dx = \frac{-1}{cosh\ x}$

Thus the integral is now:

$$\int \frac{1}{sinh^2x\ cosh\ x} dx$$

This is obviously utterly wrong. The mistake must've arisen from changing the differential variable dx to dt. However, what if I did this?

- $t = e^x$.
- Let $e^x = cosh\ x$

What would I have to do now to allow myself to plug in $cosh^2\ x$ for $e^{2x}$? Why, if I cannot do this, is this not allowed?

Comment: So we agree that $\int 1/(t^2 + 1) dt = \arctan(t) + C$ right ?

Comment: Regarding your first question, I think none of the substitutions you did are correct. For the extra question, please, write it in a new question; it will help you getting a better answer.

Comment: @Zubzub I recall that being correct, but why is my statement wrong for why I can't use a cosh identity there?

Comment: "This is equivalent to the following, with the appropriate substitution of t=ex:" Absolutely not.

Comment: The integral is $\int e^{-x}\frac{1}{1-1/e}dx$

Comment: @Did Is it not? My lecture notes identified this.

Comment: Indeed it is not, as several users took the pain to explain below. I would be curious to see your lecture notes (I mean, verbatim) on this...

Comment: @Did I apologize for my lack of diligence, the correct integral is 1/t^2-1 dt. I'll edit it. Thanks for the spot.

Comment: Are you saying that the integral $$\int \frac{1}{e^x-e^{x-1}} dx$$ becomes, using the substitution of $t = e^x$,  the integral $$\int \frac{1}{t^2-1} dt\ ?$$ Sorry but this is still wrong.

Comment: @Did Fair enough. Here's the lecture notes where it is stated: http://imgur.com/a/KMOhG

Comment: ...Which merely shows, as could be guessed from some time now, that you simply failed to copy faithfully the text of your exercise.

Comment: @Did Heavens, I just spotted that. My apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: Finally... Next: "Recall $\cosh^2x - \sinh^2x = 1$" Right. "Hence $\sinh^2x - 1 = \cosh^2x$" Hmm, no.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a small remark, not really answering the question:
It's much easyer to work out the integral by observing
$$\frac{1}{e^x - e^{x-1}} = e^{-x} \frac{1}{1 - e^{-1}}.$$
Since the latter factor is constant, it's sufficient to know the primitive of $e^{-x}$ which should be well-known.

Comment: That's a very good point, wish I spotted that.